# How come JAVA_HOME not automatically set for all users after installing openjdk-6 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, java, configuration, openjdk

On a freshly installed box, Java was not installed, so I installed openjdk-6 via `apt-get install openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jdk`.  When I try to start my Hadoop service, it complains that JAVA_HOME is not set.

Is there something that needs to be done to get JAVA_HOME set for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the packages typically sets up symlinks to the common Java binaries as `/usr/bin/java`, etc. and that's sufficient for most Java applications.

Some still want the legacy JAVA_HOME and for something like Hadoop, the best place to set it is in the global environment config file `/etc/environment` ; it will then be available in the console (TTY), terminals and the desktop.